# How to make the header take up the full width when zooming out?

Tags: html, css, zooming

When i zoom out the header doesn't take up the full-width of the page. I have two images the first is how it is supposed to look when zooming out and the second one is where it doesn't take up the full width.

Picture 1 :
[image: Picture 1]

Picture 2 :
[image: Picture 2]

I have tried with `width:100%` in the header, but it doesn't work.

```css
    * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;}

    html {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: #fff;}

    header {
    background-color: var(--background-color);
    width:100%;}
```

Comment: I want, if screen size 25% all my header content should be center, can you pls help me on this?

Comment: Try putting margin:auto to the header

Answer (score 0):

Edit 1:- Change margin-left  to 0px and margin-right to 0px. make max-width: 100%;.

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Edit -2 :-
as far as i understood , your problem now is to set the other sections centered. follow this [how to center things in css](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-things-with-style-in-css-dc87b7542689/) . If it sill doesn't  solve the problem please edit the above fiddle accordingly and specify the requirements clearly (like using id's)

Edit -3:-
Please follow the sample fiddle.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qma7n13e/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r56zg8pb/ here is my code . When i remove the max width everything messes up .

Comment: I have tried that ,but look what is happening to  the header elements they spread , and the other sections on the page should be centered (they shouldn't spread) .Here is a picture of the page after the changes https://imgur.com/sz04cer

Comment: @SarahBarlow please follow Edit-2. :)

Comment: I am trying to make a page like this (on the link) the header should take up the width and the other element to be centred. How to accomplish that? https://imgur.com/a/Cy0mLPt

Comment: Check the Edit-3 for that implementation.